# How JMS API works

Tags: java, networking, jms

I want to figure out how the `JMS API` works, I know how to use this API but my problem is to know how it works in terms of networks.

For example, when my client subscribes to receive notifications from the server, how the server send notifications to the client side without making a http request by the client? Did the JMS API use my IP in addition to my JMS session id?

The pull mechanism is completely clear: the client will send requests periodically to receive new updates, but in push mechanism the client receives notification without sending a request.

Answer (score 2):

It's entirely up to the actual JMS implementation you use how this is done.

With most implementations, a permanent TCP connection is set up between your application and the JMS server/broker, which usually uses a custom protocol on top of TCP.

As there's now a TCP connection set up, data can go both ways, you can send data to the server. The server can push data to your application.

(This is different from e.g. the HTTP protocol, where the client have to request something from the server, whilst the custom protocol used on a particular JMS implementation can initiate requests/data from either directions)